# How to display count view for event in fullcalender

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

Hello I am new to fullcalender i am able to add event in calendar but I want to show count no. of events in for particular date . So How can I do it?

Here is the example that I want to show. (highlighted in yellow)

[image]

screen 2 is my current screen

for now it's showing all events for 13th Oct , but I want to show this like if more than 3 events on for day it should look like +1 on date cell(highlighted in yellow)

```
<div class="calendar-wrap">
  <div id='calendar'></div>
</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#viewData").change(function() {

      alert($('#viewData').val());

      window.location = $('#viewData').val();
    });

  })

  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.datetimepicker').datepicker({
      timepicker: true,
      language: 'en',
      range: true,
      multipleDates: true,
      multipleDatesSeparator: " - "
    });
    jQuery("#add-event").submit(function() {
      alert("Submitted");
      var values = {};
      $.each($('#add-event').serializeArray(), function(i, field) {
        values[field.name] = field.value;
      });
      console.log(
        values
      );
    });
  });

  (function() {

    'use strict';

    jQuery(function() {

      jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        themeSystem: 'bootstrap4',
        // emphasizes business hours
        businessHours: false,
        defaultView: 'month',
        // event dragging & resizing
        editable: true,
        dayMaxEvents: true,
        // header
        header: {
          left: 'title',
          center: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay',
          right: 'today prev,next'
        },


        events: [{
            title: 'Barber',
            description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.',
            start: '2022-10-05',

            className: 'fc-bg-default',

          },
          {
            title: 'Flight Paris',
            description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.',
            start: '2022-10-08T14:00:00',

            className: 'fc-bg-deepskyblue',

            allDay: false
          },
          {
            title: 'Team Meeting',
            description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.',
            start: '2022-10-10T13:00:00',

            className: 'fc-bg-pinkred',

            allDay: false
          },
          {
            title: 'Meeting',
            description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras',
            start: '2022-10-12',
            className: 'fc-bg-lightgreen',

          },
          {
            title: 'Conference',
            description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras eu 
            pellentesque nibh.In nisl nulla,
            convallis ac nulla eget,
            pellentesque
            pellentesque magna.
            ',
            start: '2022-10-13',

            className: 'fc-bg-lightgreen',

          },


          {
            title: 'Conference',
            description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras eu 
            pellentesque nibh.In nisl nulla,
            convallis ac nulla eget,
            pellentesque pellentesque magna.
            ',
            start: '2022-10-13',

            className: 'fc-bg-lightgreen',

          },
          {
            title: 'Baby Shower',
            description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras eu 
            pellentesque nibh.In nisl nulla,
            convallis ac nulla eget,
            pellentesque pellentesque magna.
            ',
            start: '2022-10-13',

            className: 'fc-bg-default',

          },
          {
            title: 'Birthday',
            description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras eu 
            pellentesque nibh.In nisl nulla,
            convallis ac nulla eget,
            pellentesque
            pellentesque magna.
            ',
            start: '2022-10-13',

            className: 'fc-bg-default',

          },
          {
            title: 'Restaurant',
            description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras eu 
            pellentesque nibh.In nisl nulla,
            convallis ac nulla eget,
            pellentesque pellentesque magna.
            ',
            start: '2022-10-15T09:30:00',

            className: 'fc-bg-default',

            allDay: false
          },
          {
            title: 'Dinner',
            description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras eu 
            pellentesque nibh.In nisl nulla,
            convallis ac nulla eget,
            pellentesque pellentesque magna.
            ',
            start: '2022-10-15T20:00:00',

            className: 'fc-bg-default',

            allDay: false
          },
          {
            title: 'Shooting',
            description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras eu 
            pellentesque nibh.In nisl nulla,
            convallis ac nulla eget,
            pellentesque
            pellentesque magna.
            ',
            start: '2022-10-25',

            className: 'fc-bg-blue',

          },
          {
            title: 'Go Space :)',
            description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras eu 
            pellentesque nibh.In nisl nulla,
            convallis ac nulla eget,
            pellentesque
            pellentesque magna.
            ',
            start: '2022-10-27',

            className: 'fc-bg-default',

          },
          {
            title: 'Dentist',
            description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras eu 
            pellentesque nibh.In nisl nulla,
            convallis ac nulla eget,
            pellentesque
            pellentesque magna.
            ',
            start: '2022-10-29T11:30:00',

            className: 'fc-bg-blue',

            allDay: false
          }
        ],

        dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
          // jQuery('#modal-view-event-add').modal();

          location.href = ('gridViewc');


        },
        eventClick: function(event, jsEvent, view) {
          jQuery('.event-icon').html("<i class='fa fa-" + event.icon + "'></i>");
          jQuery('.event-title').html(event.title);
          jQuery('.event-body').html(event.description);
          jQuery('.eventUrl').attr('href', event.url);
          // jQuery('#modal-view-event').modal();
          location.href = ('gridViewc');

        },

        eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
          $(element).each(function() {
            $(this).attr('date-num', event.start.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
          });
        },

        eventAfterAllRender: function(view) {
          for (cDay = view.start.clone(); cDay.isBefore(view.end); cDay.add(1, 'day')) {
            var dateNum = cDay.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
            var dayEl = $('.fc-day[data-date="' + dateNum + '"]');
            var eventCount = $('.fc-event[date-num="' + dateNum + '"]').length;
            if (eventCount) {
              var html = '<span class="event-count">' +
                '<i>' +
                eventCount +
                '</i>' +
                ' Events' +
                '</span>';

              dayEl.append(html);

            }
          }
        }
      })
    });
  })(jQuery);

</script>
```

Comment: `if more than 3 events on for day it should look like +1`...so let me get this straight: if there are _3_ events or more on the day, you want it to show something which makes it look like there is _1_ event on the day? Why?

Comment: Also, any particular reason you're using a very old version of fullCalendar and not the latest one?